# Как сравнить числа и вывести результат?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Компьютер загадывает случайное число, пользователь
пытается его угадать. Пользователь вводит число до тех пор, пока не угадает или не
введет слово «Выход». Компьютер сравнивает число с введенным и сообщает
пользователю результат угадал или нет.

```
import random
print("Let'a play a game, try to choose a write number")
    while True:
        comp = random.randint(1, 2)
        'x' == comp
        text = input("enter num: ")
        if text =="stop":
            print("exit")
            break
        elif text == comp:
            print("win", comp)
        else:
            print("wtf", comp)
```

Comment: Вы сравниваете строку с числом, естественно строка никогда не может быть равна числу. Нужно сравнивать или строку со строкой, или число с числом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного не понятно, для чего вам строка:
`'x' == comp`

После того как вы проверили, что введенная строка не равна стоп, нужно перевести строку в число, для этого используйте `int()` (Нужно быть аккуратным, данная функция может бросить исключение).

А после уже сравнивать полученное число с тем, что вам вернул `randint`.
Про операторы сравнения можно посмотреть [здесь](http://pythonicway.com/python-operators).

Comment: "для этого используйте int()" спасибо за подсказку. Заработало